# How to dynamically assign a certain generic type to a List?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, generics

The question title feels quite clumsy. I am grateful for an edit.
I am trying to create a reusable query to return a `List` of objects of a certain kind that is specified by an assigned `String`.
This won't work but I suppose it will make clear what I am trying to do:

```
public List<?> getAll(String type) {
    Class clazz = Class.forName(type);
    return (List<clazz>) em.createQuery("SELECT t from " + type + " t").getResultList();
}
```

Comment: Why you did not use simple List without Generics?

Comment: I don't think this is possible due to type erasure.

Comment: Do you need something like a list to put the data that you fetch from the DB or something like that you are trying to do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the type's class:

```
public <T> List<T> getAll(Class<T> type) {
  return em.createQuery("SELECT t from " + type.getSimpleName() + " t").getResultList();
}
```

Note that this will still generate a warning, since `getResultList()` returns a raw list.

*Edit*:

If you only have a fully qualified class name, i.e. you need to call `Class.forName()`, there's no way to know the class at compile time - and since generics (almost) are a compile time feature only (hint: type erasure) they won't help in that case.

You could still call the generic method with a class retrieved by `Class.forName()` like this:

```
List<?> l = getAll( Class.forName( typeName ));
```

You might also not need to get the class object itself, if it is just for the query (however, it might make sense to first check that the string is the name of an existing class). In this case your method might look like this:

```
public List<?> getAll(String type) {
   return em.createQuery("SELECT t from " + type + " t").getResultList();
}
```

This variant would also allow you to either pass in a fully qualified class name or an entity name, i.e. it would be somewhat more flexible.

Alternatively you could return `List<Object>`, which would allow you to add further objects to the list (but beware, you could add anything).

That being said, I'd use the first option whenever possible and the second option as a fallback when the concrete type (or at least some interface) is unknown at compile time.

Comment: You can create `TypedQuery` instead.

Comment: how can I get `Class<T>` from a `String`?

Comment: @Lester I'll update the answer, but don't you have a way to use the class directly instead of the class name?